# Can we script AS2(Applicability Statement 2) request using JMeter & Loadrunner?

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

I want to script an AS2 request using these tools, as AS2 follows encoding/decoding pattern while sending and recieving data ,so how to deal with them. If these tools are able to handle then what are the other factors should be considered while recording & scripting , like do we need to do any other configuration in tools?

Comment: AS2 is based on HTTP. JMeter or LoadRunner should support your business transactions.

Comment: Yes,  I agree but for sending/receiving As2 uses encoding/decoding scheme , so do these tools already offer this facility without doing any additional configuration?

Comment: Yes. DFE in LoadRunner. JSON plug-in for JMeter.

Comment: Ok, please suggest what are the other requirements I need to ask the client before recording the AS2 request? As far as I am aware the concept I think I need to ask certificates(to get public key) use for security purpose and encoding/decoding scheme their api is using.

Comment: Get the certificate and its details such as expiration date, version etc. Rest, you will figure out during scripting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am including a link to the Data Format Extensions information for LoadRunner.  This part of the tool deals explicitly with decoding and encoding on the fly.  If AS2 uses a standardized encoding model, such as Base64, then you may have an out of the box solution.  Otherwise small amounts of code related to the decode and encode may be required on your end.

[Data Format Extensions (DFE) Overview](http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/c_web_data_format_extensions.htm?Highlight=decoding)

Comment: Ok, please suggest what are the other requirements I need to ask the client before recording the AS2 request? As far as I am aware the concept I think I need to ask certificates(to get public key) use for security purpose and encoding/decoding scheme their api is using.

Comment: Please read the article.  For the encoding/decoding you need to understand the algorithm involves and whether it is public or unique to the client code.  Certificates only matter if it is encrypted.  But you have only indicated encoding, which is different than encryption.  Encoding requires no cipher key

Comment: My bad , actually I mixed the both things(encoding and encryption) AS2 standard works with some of the strongest encryption and signature algorithms available commercially.
So for decryption I need a key which is shared through certificates
second the scheme to convert data in Human readable format.
Please give your suggestions on this to script this through Loadrunner.

Comment: As long as you have the encryption/decryption algorithms and a key then you can still use the data format extensions to handle that work on the fly